# Edit date field code on multiple Word Documents

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have multiple word documents that have a date field code displaying the current date. I need a way to modify each document so that it shows the **CreateDate** field instead of **Date**.

The format for each field is currently **DATE \@ "dd MMMM yyyy"** on each of the documents, but I would like it changed to **CREATEDATE \@ "dd MMMM yyyy"**.

Is there anyway I can automate this for multiple documents, instead of having to go into each one separately?

If it helps, there is only 1 date field in all of the documents and they are in .doc format

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used the [VBA Find & Replace](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/vba_find_and_replace.html) add-in to update multiple documents. The claim is;

> VBA Find and Replace© provides a method for finding and replacing text anywhere in a document

You will have to investigate whether the "anywhere" includes field codes.